# android cannot get the text and do the login

Tags: java, android, authentication

I am trying to create a login page to my Android App. I have 2 editview and a button. I am using a static user credentials to login. when I run the app, and try to login with the correct username and password, it gives incorrect credential message.

here is my code, it is a very simple piece of code

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    EditText user_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    EditText password =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

    if(user_name.getText().toString()=="rotanet" && password.getText().toString()=="rotanet"){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        TextView lbl_error = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_error);
        lbl_error.setText("");
    }
    else{
        TextView lbl_error = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_error);
        lbl_error.setText("wrong credentials!");
    }
}
```

Comment: else executed if any field(password or user name) not containd rotanet and use .equals() method insted of == operator .

Comment: in Java, you should compare Strings using String equals() method. not ==

Comment: thank you very much. I sometimes forget easy things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using == to compare strings.

Use .equals insted.

```
if(user_name.getText().toString().equals("rotanet") && password.getText().toString().equals("rotanet")){
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `==` to compare strings

Example:

```
 if(user_name.getText().toString().equals("rotanet") && password.getText().toString().equals("rotanet"))
{
stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `gettext().toString().equals("goodpass")` instead of `==` when you check the password.
`==` compares reference, not value.

Answer (score 1):

Use .equals

```
if(user_name.getText().toString().equals("rotanet") && password.getText().toString().equals("rotanet"))
{
 //dosomething  
}
```

the == operator determines if 2 references point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is not used to compare contents of strings. Try `user_name.getText().toString().equals("rotanet")`

== tests for reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

use equals method for comparison

```
if((user_name.getText().toString().equals("rotanet") && password.getText().toString().equals("rotanet"))
{

}
```